# Is there any better method of adding extra parameters during object serialization?

Tags: c++, serialization

I want to add indent during serialization of object. But since `operator<<` can only contains `2` parameters:

```
struct A {
    int member;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& str, const A& a)
{
  return str;
}
```

Now my solution is like this:

```
struct A {
    int m1;
    int m2;
};

void print(const A& a, const int indent)
{
    cout << string(indent, '\t') << m1 << endl;
    cout << string(indent + 1, '\t') << m2 << endl;
}
```

Is there any better method of adding extra parameters during object serialization?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a tuple or pair and send it to a `operator<<`function

or you could also do something like

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& param)  
{  
    auto width = os.width();
    auto fill = os.fill();
    os << std::setfill(fill) << std::right;
    os << std::setw(width) << param.m1 << std::endl;
    os << std::setw(width) << fill << param.m2 << std::endl;
    return os;  
}  

int main()
{
    struct A a{1,2};

    std::cout.width(4);
    std::cout.fill('\t');
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```